# Convert small bash command to php

Tags: php, bash, unix

I have inherited a bash/unix command/job that I would like to convert to php format, which I am better at. Problem is that I am not good at unix commands, would somebody like to help?

```
datofrom=$(date +%Y%m%d%H --date="+1 hour")
datoto=$(date +%Y%m%d%H --date="+6 days")
#echo $datofrom
#echo $datoto
curl "https://secure.someadress.com/file/key&parameters" > filename
```

Comment: if you read each line out loud, and make an educated guess as to what it is exactly doing, then you'll see the conversion in php is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use `shell_exec`. See [manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.shell-exec.php).

```
$datefrom = shell_exec('date +%Y%m%d%H --date="+1 hour"');
$tateto = shell_exec('date +%Y%m%d%H --date="+6 days"');
```

For the curl part, use `curl_exec`. See [manual](http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-exec.php)

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_exec($ch);
// work with $ch before close
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP code:

```
    $datofrom = date("YmdH",strtotime("+1 hour"));
    $datoto = date("YmdH",strtotime("+6 days"));
    $res = shell_exec('curl "https://secure.someadress.com/file/key&parameters"');
    file_put_contents($filename, $res);
```